# Automatically Generated rhythm game Flash Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to create an automatically generated Rhythm game for Flash Action Script 3 ?

But not just randomly generated, generated from the notes of a song. Or is that something I have to do manually?

How would I go about doing either of these?

I am currently following this tutorial: http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-make-a-rhythm-game-in-as3-part-4/ so perhaps it can be made to fit around this? (Go to the final part and View Source to see the full thing)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by rhythm game, check out the `computeSpectrum()` function of the `SoundMixer` class: [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum%28%29)

There's an example of it working in the link, but basically what it does is take a snapshot of the current sound wave and puts normalised (-1 to 1) values in a ByteArray. What you do with those values is up to you - e.g. you might use them as a height field to generate terrain for example.

Repeat this every frame, and you get the gist

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

First off, there is nothing already built in, to my knowledge. There may be something lurking around Google that someone else wrote, but you'd need to dig around for that (though I assume you already did.)

Generated from the notes of a song. Hmm, this will take some serious ingenuity and coding on your part. I'll point you in the right direction, but it is up to you to write the code. No one here will do it for you, but [we'll happily help with specific problems in your code.](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

The crazy (yet potentially more fun) approach MAY BE to derive the data in a similar manner that an audio visualizer does...but I can't guarantee that will work. This would work best with MIDI-generated, single instrument songs. [Here is a tutorial on visualizers.](http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/01/creating-an-audio-visualiser/)

A second approach may be to actually convert MIDI files directly. Again, I can't guarantee it will work, but it would theoretically be possible, seeing how MIDI files store data to begin with. [Here's an answer on playing MIDI files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16257322/472647), to get you started. Consider looking through their class.

However, the "easiest" approach would be to come up with some sort of system by which you store the note values for a song. You can manually enter the values in an array, or in a data file ([such as XML](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/)) that you can load.

I put "easiest" in quotes because you'd have to account for a LOT of information - not just note values, but note duration, rhythm, and rests.

Anyway, those are just a few ideas to get you started. Good luck!